# Can not compress recyled bitmap in android

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

> I am taking the image from gallery and doing compression as well. In Piece of code i am getting Can not compress recyled bitmap Error., only on few devices.I tried changing the code as well , but its happening only very rare case. couldn't able to find the solution, Please see my method

```
 public byte[] getByteArrayOfImage(int position) {
    byte[] bytes = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap loadedImage = this.images.get(position);
    try {
        float imgWidth = (float) loadedImage.getWidth();
        float imgHeight = (float) loadedImage.getHeight();
        if (imgWidth > MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH) {
            float scaleFactor = imgWidth / MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH;
            loadedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedImage, (int) (imgWidth / scaleFactor), (int) (imgHeight / scaleFactor), false);
        }
        loadedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, Constants.SCALE_IMAGE, byteArrayOutputStream);
        bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    } finally {
        try {
            byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
            Helper.getInstance(mContext).recycleBitmap(loadedImage);// Recycling the bitmap image.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
    return bytes;
}
```

> Error is on `loadedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(` this line, Please give me the suggestion whats needs to be done.

Comment: Show the stacktrace please.

Comment: You mean the Error Log?

Comment: Yeah, that's what we're usually looking for in this case, the exact stack trace from logcat.

Comment: @ci_ Please find the logcat : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't compress a recycled bitmap
                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.checkRecycled(Bitmap.java:357)
                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:998)
                                                                        at com.app.package.util.Helper.getByteArrayOfImage(Helper.java:366)